# Magic methods + Reflection API = can't investigate class properties. Why?

Tags: php, oop, magic-methods

If I use magic methods. While using reflection API, I can't investigate class properties.. Why is it so?

> **EDIT**

What is Reflection API? pls do not refer me php.net i didnt understood that.. guide me in your words plsss

Comment: Can you provide more specific details of what is not working and how do yoou try to achieve it?

Comment: I am going through a book which has stated this, and marked this as a limitation in Magic Method... Thats all what I know about it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using magic methods to access properties, those properties will generally not be present in the class' definition.

Your class' definition will generally look like this :

```
class MyClass {
    private $data;
    public function __get($name) {
        return $this->data[$name];
    }
    public function __set($name, $value) {
        $this->data[$name] = $value;
    }
}
```

As there is no *real properties* -- there is on only a `$data` array, which will be used by the magic methods `__get` an `__set` as a big data-store -- those cannot be seen by the Reflection API.

That's one of the problems caused by using magic methods : they are used to access properties *(or methods, with `__call`)* which are not there -- and the Reflection API can only see what's there.

Comment: Reversing and asking the key word "Reflecton API" whats that basically used for.. and y it does not do what u have specified above?

Answer (score -2):

A possible solution might be to increase the scope of $data to protected:

```
class MyClass {
    protected $data;
    public function __get($name) {
        return $this->data[$name];
    }
    public function __set($name, $value) {
        $this->data[$name] = $value;
    }
}
```

This way, extended classes can access the array as they see fit and collect runtime defined properties.